# configuring rewrite rules in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect

I have ngnix webserver running on port 80. I have a Nodejs running on 9000 port. I need to rewrite the request coming from my nginx to app server which is running on port 3000.

I tried configuring with below options but it is redirecting to the browser and not forwarding to the app server. When there is a request for /hosts.json it need to be redirected to `http://appserver.corp.cn.com:3000/hosts/hosts.json`. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
location / {
             rewrite ^/hosts.json http://appserver.corp.cn.com:3000/hosts.json permanent;
             rewrite ^/hosts/bu.json http://appserver.corp.cn.com:3000/hosts/bu.json permanent;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
             proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I need to set `proxy_pass` for the below url pattern

```
location  ~ ^/hosts/bu/(.*)/app/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass   http://appserver.cnma.com:3000/hosts/bu/$1/app/$2;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want redirects, then you have to use `proxy_pass` to appropriate server

Comment: How to do that? I mean what is the syntax for redirecting based on the url pattern?

Comment: Could you be more accurate with word "redirect"? Redirect means "tell browser to go there", while you actually want to go there yourself (using nginx's proxy_pass) and give browser an answer. Is it correct description of your problem?

Comment: Yes. I do not want to "tell browser to go there". I want to go there by the ui server. How to use the proxy_pass with different url patterns. Please help mw with an example.

Comment: Why so specific location? Would not `location /hosts/bu/` be enough?

Comment: I want the location for `~ ^/hosts/bu/(.*)/app/(.*)$` pattern with parameters. When I call the the values `/bu/value` is getting passed. The second parameter is not getting passed

Comment: But you combine them into exactly the same url. Updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to proxy to different servers based on URI. There is a natural way for this, just out different `proxy_pass` directives in appropriate `location`s:

```
server {
  ...

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
  }

  location /hosts.json {
    proxy_pass http://appserver.corp.cn.com:3000;
  }

  location /hosts/bu.json {
    proxy_pass http://appserver.corp.cn.com:3000;
  }

  location /hosts/bu/ {
    proxy_pass http://appserver.corp.cn.com:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is what I was looking for. I have some issue when passing the parameters though. I have updated my question with the specific pattern which is not working for me. Could you let me know where I am going wrong.